# How separate latitude and longitude into two columns from dataframe using regex

Tags: python, json, latitude-longitude

After using google maps api I get a list of all business it find,[image]

on the column geometry I get this data for each business:

> {'location': {'lat': 39.7904306, 'lng': -86.1631634}, 'viewport':
> {'northeast': {'lat': 39.79635710000001, 'lng': -86.15916770000001},
> 'southwest': {'lat': 39.78564629999999, 'lng': -86.16786649999999}}}

I need to separate latitude and longitude into two separate columns one for each coordinate, after trying regex:

```
import re 
Health_centers['Venue Latitude'] = Health_centers['geometry'].str.extract(r"[^}]*")
```

I only get to extract

> {'location': {'lat': 39.7904306, 'lng': -86.1631634

there is a way to combine strip and regex to do it with one code line?

Comment: Why are you using a regex here? Why not parse the JSON and extract the values you want?

Comment: For some reason I forget that, that will be enough

Comment: `#normalize geometry json content
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
Health_centers2 = pd.json_normalize(Health_centers['geometry'])`                                 and then concat                                                                                                                  `Health_centers3 = Health_centers.join(Health_centers2)`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that I am missing something, but does this line suffice? It makes a list containing both `lat` and `lng`. You could also get them separately if that is better.

```
list(Health_centers['geometry']['location'].values())
```

If the data is actually a string, this would do the trick.

```
import json    
list(json.loads(Health_centers['geometry'])['location'].values())
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hey, I tried to write a regex for you `'lat':[^0-9]-?[0-9]*[.]-?[0-9]+|'lng':[^0-9]-?[0-9]*[.]-?[0-9]+`
Like this you can get the desired output but I think you can just simply parse the JSON and get the lat and long properties easily.